# Paste e.clipboardData.items always undefined

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt

I'm using Chrome for my GWT app via `JSNI` to get the `clipboardData`

```
$doc.onpaste = function( e ) {
    var pastedText = undefined;
    if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
        var items = e.clipboardData.items; // undefined!
    }
}
```

Not sure why items is undefined when `clipboardData` and `clipboardData.getData` is not undefined. What could be wrong in my app?

Comment: Why do you test `e.clipboardData.getData` in the `if` and then use `e.clipboardData.items`? Shouldn't you be testing the property you're trying to use?

Comment: What is the correct approach?